# How do Tensorflow and tf.data.Dataset use memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to reduce memory usage during tf model training so models can be trained on AWS containers without running out of memory. I was looking into `tf.data.Dataset` to help with this. Increasing speed to reduce AWS costs would also be a bonus.

The pseudo code looks like this:

```
def create_model():
    # some keras Dense or LSTM model
    return model

def load_dataset(filepath):
    # load csv file and create numpy array
    return arrays

def create_sequences(arrays, sequence_length):
    # create sequences for LSTM network from numpy arrays
    return x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test

def train(model, x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test):
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, batch_size=64)
    return model

def main():
    model = create_model()
    arrays = load_dataset(filepath)
    x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = create_sequences(arrays)
    model = train(model, x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test)
```

I'm a bit confused at how Tensorflow manages memory. The csv files contain timeseries float data, fairly simple stuff, and are <10MB usually, but when loaded as numpy sequences they can be 50-300MB according to `sys.getsizeof(x_train)`, which makes sense as if the `sequence_length` becomes long there is a lot of duplicate data.

I have tried to use `tf.data.Dataset` to increase performance and help reduce memory as it contains functions to cache to memory or to file, so if I change one of the above functions:

```
def create_sequences(arrays, sequence_length):
    # create sequences for LSTM network from numpy arrays

    training_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
    validation_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test, y_test))

    training_data = training_data.cache().batch(64).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    validation_data = validation_data.cache().batch(64).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

    return training_data, validation_data
```

The `.cache()` function caches the dataset to memory. But what I don't understand is, wasn't it already in memory when it was just numpy data? How is this different?

If I understand correctly, Python should free the 50MB-300MB memory that the numpy arrays were using when the `create_sequences()` function finishes running, but now the data I loaded is just in a different format as a tensorflow dataset.

I also tried using `.cache("my_file")` to cache the data to a file and load it as needed for each batch, but it only creates this file during training. So my data is still in memory the entire time.

When comparing code run using the memory cache vs. file cache vs without use of tf datasets, my system seemed to use the same 6.7GB of memory every time (just monitoring by eye with a system monitor)

There was no speed increase, which I think is mostly due to the batches being too small to see any benefit from the dataset object. But it seems like using `tf.data.Dataset` is giving me no benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tf.data` API functions in a declarative manner: you declare all your steps one by one, and the pipeline will execute all those steps for each epoch of your training, while leveraging multi processing for you.

When calling the `cache` method stores the dataset in memory (or local storage) at the current stage N of your pipeline. So, by moving costly operations before that stage N, like reading a file on disk or performing costly data manipulation, you avoid those operations to be repeated for each epoch.

In your case, you are doing the data reading outside of the `tf.data` Pipeline: there's no operation to cache. Even so, I doubt that you would gain anything by moving the file reading and loading to TF by the look of your code, as your data fits in memory, and it looks like all the costly operations (like formatting your data) is done only once before the training phase.

If you want to optimize your training pipeline, you should use a profiler, like the [TensorFlow profiler](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler). This will give you insights on where is your bottleneck. Here, I doubt that it's the data pipeline.

You can also give a look at the guide: [Better performance with the tf.data API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance)

Comment: I think I understand. I was thinking there would be a way to store data on disk and only load the current batch during each epoch, and possibly prefetching the next batch whilst the current batch is training. Is this not the right way to do this?

Comment: What you describe can be done if you do the reading part of the pipeline with the tf.data API. But this is only advantageous if your whole dataset does not fit in memory.  If you want to know what part of your pipeline to improve, I encourage you again to use a profiler.